# Is psychological egoism, or some other descriptive theory about some inescapable pattern of human nature, compatible with normativity?

Tags: ethics, psychology, metaethics, philosophy-of-psychology

Can true normative statements exist if our behaviour is determined by some uncontrollable process? If we can only act in our self-interest, is the norm 'you ought not kill' reasonable to hold someone to even if it is in their best interest to kill someone? And can this be fixed with a softer form of psychological egoism?

Comment: Some human traits are enforced by a long history of biological evolution. Their power can be difficult to detect and also difficult to control. - But to understand your sentences no. 2 and 3 it would be helpful, if you can provide a concrete and realistic example.